# Sum Approximation

Tags: calculus, integration, approximation, riemann-sum

Consider $\int_{4}^{9} \frac{1}{\sqrt x} \ dx$

1) Find a value of $n$ where $|L_n - R_n| \leq 0.1$

2) Use that value of $n$ to find $L_n$ and $R_n$

3) If you were to take the average of the Left-hand sum and the Right-hand sum, will your approximation be larger or smaller than the integral? $$\\$$

***$L_n$ is left-hand sum**

***$R_n$ is right-hand sum**

$$\\$$ I have no clue on how to go about this problem. I was think I might have to use the error formulas but I'm not certain.

Your help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that the left hand sum is $\displaystyle \frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f\left(a+\displaystyle \frac{k}{n}(b-a)\right)$

Similarly, the right hand sum is $\displaystyle \frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(a+\displaystyle \frac{k}{n}(b-a)\right).$

They're almost the same. The difference is that the rectangle at the beginning of the left hand sum is "replaced" with the rectangle at the end of the right hand sum.

So we have the difference of areas is $\displaystyle L_n-R_n=\frac{b-a}{n}\left(f(a)-f(b)\right)$.

We need that $|L_n-R_n| \leq 0.1$. We have that $\displaystyle f(a)-f(b)=\frac{1}{6}$, and that $b-a=5$.

Plugging right in gives us $\displaystyle \frac{5}{6}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \leq \frac{1}{10}$. (We just drop absolute value because $n$ is positive).

Now we isolate $n$ to get $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{3}{25}$.

Flipping the inequality gives us $\displaystyle n \geq \frac{25}{3}$.

Because we can't have half a rectangle, we say that $\boxed{n \geq 9}$.

---

$L_n = \displaystyle \frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f\left(a+\displaystyle \frac{k}{n}(b-a)\right)=\displaystyle \frac{b-a}{n}f(a) + \frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f\left(a+\displaystyle \frac{k}{n}(b-a)\right)$

$R_n = \displaystyle \frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(a+\displaystyle \frac{k}{n}(b-a)\right)=\displaystyle \frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f\left(a+\displaystyle \frac{k}{n}(b-a)\right)+\frac{b-a}{n}f(b)$

That's how $\displaystyle L_n-R_n = \frac{b-a}{n}(f(a)-f(b))$ comes about.

Comment: "Notice that the left hand sum is $\displaystyle \frac{b-a}{n}\sum_0^{n-1}f\left(a+\displaystyle \frac{b-a}{n}\right)$"

Comment: So when we try to approximate the integral, we want to break it into little pieces. I think you got that. So the total length of our rectangles is $b-a$, which is how much we're integrating. So if we split it into $n$ rectangles, we have $\displaystyle \frac{b-a}{n}$. And for each rectangle, we need it's corresponding $f(x)$ for the height

Comment: Can you explain why you didn't evaluate the integral when got 
$\frac{1}{6}$?

Comment: Evaluating $f(a)-f(b)$ doesn't require the integral.

Comment: Do you see the difference in the sums, though?

Comment: No I'm still confused, I was just going to ask you about that

Comment: let me type it up in that case

Comment: check the answer

Comment: what about question 3) ?

Comment: In my notes I have: $L_n$ = △$x$ [$f(a)+f(b)$] and $R_n$ = △$x$ [$f(b)+f(a)$], so is that the same as what you've said?

Comment: The way it looks to me, you wrote shorthand for s bigger expression

Comment: Okay, I'll work with your expressions.

Comment: Also, for #2 what equations do I use to find $L_n$ and $R_n$?

Comment: Do I use △$x$ [$f(a)-f(b)$] for $L_n$ & △$x$ [$f(b)-f(a)$] for $R_n$ ?

Comment: that doesn't quite make sense to me. delta x is the length of each rectangle, or (b-a)/n

Comment: I am quite confused as to what equation @AmR needs to use to find both $L_n$ and $R_n$